# Condition for the existence of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Could you please explain and solve this problem for me? I would really appreciate it. The more depth of explanation, the better.

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be non-collinear vectors. Show that the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a triangle ABC with the properties:
BC = a; CA = b; AB = c;
is: 
a x b = b x c = c x a;
[-- Image - click here --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx7jj.jpg)

Comment: What have you attempted yet ? Have you considered that  the norm of a cross-product can be expressed as the measure of a certain area ?

Comment: Hint: $$\vec a\times \vec b - \vec c\times \vec a=0 $$
$$\vec a\times \vec b + \vec a\times \vec c=0 $$
$$\vec a\times (\vec b+\vec c)=0$$